# Mysql update with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a point system were there's a quiz. when they click submit from the quiz i want them to get +1 into points in mysql. i got a datbase called login and table users, and in the users i want the points to be updated with 1+ when they have taken the quiz.
the code for the quiz_form i use:

```
:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registration Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="328" border="0" align="center">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="script.php">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><h2 style="color:#FF0000">Quiz1</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>UserName:</td>
<td>
<input name="txtusername" type="text" id="txtusername" value="<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{

     echo "".$_SESSION['username'];


}

else
    header ("location: welcome1.html");

?>
" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Who is Obama?</td>
<td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>What was the bing thing that were going to happend in 2012?</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is a farrari?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />


</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is a spoon used for?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Witch letter does this url start with?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Are COD a game?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="btnRegister" id="btnRegister" value="submit" />

</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<table width="328" border="0" align="center">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="script2.php">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><h2 style="color:#FF0000">Quiz2</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>UserName:</td>
<td>
<input name="txtusername" type="text" id="txtusername" value="<?php

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{

     echo "".$_SESSION['username'];


}

else
    header ("location: welcome1.html");

?>
" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Who evented facebook?</td>
<td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>What is a cat?</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is a lamborgini?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />


</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is goodel used for?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is the last letter in this url</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Are Counter strik a game?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="btnRegister" id="btnRegister" value="submit" />

</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<table width="328" border="0" align="center">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="script3.php">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><h2 style="color:#FF0000">Quiz3</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>UserName:</td>
<td>
<input name="txtusername" type="text" id="txtusername" value="<?php

if ($_SESSION['username'])
{

     echo "".$_SESSION['username'];


}

else
    header ("location: welcome1.html");

?>
" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is yourube used for?</td>
<td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>What is a dog?</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is a kebab?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />


</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Who is the most famed tenager in 2012/13?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What is the 4th letter in this url?</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>100*2 - 5 +105 -55 +45= </td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtnummer" id="txtnummer" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="btnRegister" id="btnRegister" value="submit" />

</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the script i use for the quiz:

```
<?php
//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'root';
$password    =    '';
//=============Data Base Information=================
$database    =    'login';

$conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information is not Correct'); //Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

//===============End Server Configuration============

//=============Starting Registration Script==========


$username    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtusername']);

//=============To Encrypt Password===================

//============New Variable of Password is Now with an Encrypted Value========

if(isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) //===When I will Set the Button to 1 or Press Button to register
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
echo "Sorry but you can only take a quize once:S";

}else{

mysql_query ("insert into quiz(username)values('$username')");
$sql = "UPDATE users SET points = COALESCE(level,0)+1 WHERE username = $username";
header('location: succes.php');
}
}
?>
```

again, this work great. but i just need so they get 1 more points. so if they have 10 points and take this quiz they get 11 after clicking submit

Comment: There is MUCH too much stuff in this question. If you can't reduce it to what's important for the question, you probably asked too early or don't understand your code well enough!

Comment: Do NOT use the ancient mysql_* functions anymore! They are insecure and inefficient. Instead use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements!

Comment: The question is: What code do i need to get so when people click submit then they get 1 more point. update code

Comment: The answer is. Understand your code so you can ask a precise question. Sorry but this sounds too much like: I copied this piece of code from somewhere, fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this update query

```
 $qry = "UPDATE users SET points = points+1 WHERE username = $username"
```

and as was said in comments, start using PDO or MySqli with prepared statements for your future codes, as old mysql commands are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, hah i will if i manage to do it:)

Comment: your welcome, glad I could help out :). I am changing over my old code for some of my projects now as well

Comment: i found out i didnt work:/ but i think it's the right code but nothing happen. i didnt get 1 points more in my table. BTW the code over has an another table then were the points are

Comment: that is the problem-.- it uses another table... how do i add the code under else and change table?

Comment: which table does it use?

Comment: the quiz script and form are in table:quiz but the points are in table users. i think the code were right but it didnt seem to work thou:/ i thught it worked but it was something else. i added the code under }else{

Comment: That code is correct, but there is another way to implement it. You could get the current score in a variable, then +1 to it, then set the new points to the new score

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem over here:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET points = COALESCE(level,0)+1 WHERE username = $username";
```

so, if you are doing like this.

try this,

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET points = COALESCE(level+1,0) WHERE username = $username";
```

Comment: i dont get error or enything but it just seems to dont work. nothing else happens